# There are multiple option I use to select only one using for?

Tags: html, ionic2

[image]I have a languages option if I select one  only one language should be selected in UI...

But in my code what happening means if I select one means the another language selecting it should not happened and the other thing is only English language is appearing no other languages are appearing..

Below is my code:-

home.html:-

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>
       <img src="assets/images/home/KmartText.png">
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
            <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
            <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
        </button>    
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="contact" item-left></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown" item-right></ion-icon>
    Gmail
    </ion-item>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
    <ion-item (click)="doSomething()">
    Languages
    <ion-icon name="add" item-right *ngIf="languageShow"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon name="remove" item-right *ngIf="languageHide"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf="languageHide" >
    <ion-item *ngFor=" let language of languages" (click)="doSomething(language)">
    <ion-label>{{language.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio item-left></ion-radio> 
    </ion-item>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="home" item-left></ion-icon>
      My Account
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="clipboard" item-left></ion-icon>
      Orders
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="alert" item-left></ion-icon>
      Notification
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="cart" item-left></ion-icon>
      My Cart
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Rest } from '../../providers/network/rest';

import { Logger } from '../../providers/logger/logger';

import { ProductListPage } from '../product-list/product-list';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  mySlideOptions = {
    initialSlide: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: 1500,
    pager: true
  };

  languages =[ {
    id: 1,
    name: 'English'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Hindi'
  },{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Telugu'
  },{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tamil'
  }];


  languageShow:boolean = true;
  languageHide:boolean = false;

  doSomething(language: any)
  { 

 console.log(language.name); 


    if(this.languageShow){
      this.languageShow= false;
      this.languageHide = true;
    }
    else{
      this.languageShow= true;
      this.languageHide = false; 
    }
 }
```

[image: Below is my image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre setting the `<ion-label>` to `<ion-label>English</ion-label>` so there will always be English. The place where you print `{{language.name}}` will probably be under your content, so

Update it to `<ion-label>{{language.name}}</ion-label>`

Then in your `<ion-item>` you set the `(click)` on a list? Try binding it to a function

`<ion-item *ngFor=" let language of languages" (click)="doSomething(language)">`

then in your **ts**

`doSomething(language: any) { console.log(language.name); }`

**edit**

```
  <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>
       <img src="assets/images/home/KmartText.png">
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
            <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
            <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
        </button>    
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="contact" item-left></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown" item-right></ion-icon>
    Gmail
    </ion-item>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item (click)="toggleLanguages()">
          Languages
          <ion-icon name="add" item-right *ngIf="languageShow"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="remove" item-right *ngIf="languageHide"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="languageHide" >

          <!-- All radio's in a radio group -->
          <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let language of languages" (click)="doSomething(language)">
              <ion-label>{{language.name}}</ion-label>
              <ion-radio item-left [value]="language.id"></ion-radio> 
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>

        </div>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="home" item-left></ion-icon>
              My Account
         </ion-item>

         <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="clipboard" item-left></ion-icon>
              Orders
         </ion-item>

         <ion-item>
           <ion-icon name="alert" item-left></ion-icon>
             Notification
         </ion-item>

         <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="cart" item-left></ion-icon>
            My Cart
         </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

**ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';   

import { Rest } from '../../providers/network/rest';    
import { Logger } from '../../providers/logger/logger';    
import { ProductListPage } from '../product-list/product-list';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

   languageShow: boolean = true;
   languageHide: boolean = false;
   selectedLanguage: number = 1;

   mySlideOptions = {
     initialSlide: 1,
     loop: true,
     autoplay: 1500,
     pager: true
   };

   languages =[ 
      {id: 1, name: 'English'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Hindi'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Telugu'},
      {id: 4, name: 'Tamil'}
  ];

  contructor() {

  }

  doSomething()
  { 
     // do something with the language here
     console.log(this.selectedLanguage);
     this.toggleLanguages();
  }

  // this is for toggling your languages dropdown
  toggleLanguages(){
    this.languageShow = !this.languageShow;
    this.languageHide = !this.languageHide;
 }
```

Also check out the docs for [RadioGroup](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/radio/RadioGroup/)

Comment: Bro i have changed the code what ever u have given to me but i am getting errors

Comment: Ok let me edit the question and provide you with the **entire** code

Comment: edited, you changed 2 `(click)` events instead of just the on on the language :)

Comment: bro if i  have selected one language the dropdown should go up and here what happening means all the languages are selecting

Comment: i have sended u the first screen shot all the languages are selected they are appearing in blue color and there what have to happen means only whatever the language we have to select

Comment: Edited, you will have to add a `RadioGroup` and if you want to open/close the dropdown just call `toggleLanguages()`

Comment: Thanku very much bro

Comment: @Babu do not try to edit the **answer** to your question with a new/other problem. Either edit your **question** or create a new one